# php-file manager db design (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

Info about images (width/height) are irrelevant. If i need that i'll put it in another table but i don't need images info. What do you think about this db design? What do you think about MyISAM vs InnoDB for specific tables?

Thank you, I appreciate any feedback.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `directory`;
CREATE TABLE `directory` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `file`;
CREATE TABLE `file` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `fk_directory_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tag`;
CREATE TABLE `tag` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tags_files`;
CREATE TABLE `tags_files` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_file_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_tag_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since only "ajreal" answered this question i decided that base for my db design will be db design i suggested. Thanks ajreal for the answer(voteup:)). I know, ajreal, about storing all additional info(users, rights, acl, image sizes, ... and all the rest "small infos" that should be stored:) i just wanted to hear another opinions). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

- column `name` should be unique
- and it should not using `utf8_unicide_ci` for this column, due to case sensitives,

for example, in linux (not in window)

`example.jpg != example.JPG`

using ci will cause the unique name problem

- if you require lots of write, innodb should be more appropriate
- other images additional info like, width, height can be stored into table in order to facility search/filter
- unlikely you would like to keep versions of the file, but you should store the information about creator (like user_id), so, you can trace back information easily

Comment: Why should column name be unique? I can have this in my file system: A>B>A>B (where > means 'has subdirectory')!

Comment: since i am using č, ć, ž, š, đ characters and i have to sort files by their filename (a, b, c, č, ć,...)what do you suggest instead of utf8_unicode_ci, what is best alternative?

Comment: @predrag.music - there are pros and cons each, these characters can be represented in iso-8859-*, and is possible to store utf-8 data into latin table

Comment: @ajareal: i used mb_substr() for some apps i inherited but i can't shake the feeling that it is messy...